# Почему Slick slider не активируется циклом?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    let classes = [];
    let i = 0;

    const sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.slick-super-slider');

    sliders.forEach(item => {
      i++;
      const sliderUniqum = '.slider-uniqum' + i;
      item.classList.add(sliderUniqum);
      classes.push(sliderUniqum);
    });

    classes.forEach(cssClass => {
      console.log(cssClass);
      $(cssClass).slick({
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        prevArrow: false,
        nextArrow: $('.next-slide'),
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Создаётся переменная строка, создаётся массив, в котором будут храниться уникальные строки создается счетчик `i` для создания уникальных строк.

Получаем по селектору все слайдеры, "форычим", генерируем уникальные строки и добавляем класс слайдеру, пушим уникальную строку в массив.

Проходимся "форычем" по массиву и пытаемся инициализировать слайдер, но он не инициализируется, помогите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, что достаточно сделать так

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   
  var sliders = $('.slick-super-slider');
  var nextArrows = $('.next-slide');

  sliders.each(function(index, element) {
    var $slider = $(element);
    var $nextArrow = $(nextArrows[index]);

    $slider.slick({
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 3,
      prevArrow: false,
      nextArrow: $nextArrow,
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Отметьте свой ответ как правильный и другие пользователи знали что ответ на вопрос есть. (нажмите на серую галочку слева, чтобы она стала зеленой)